# How do I define a struct in C++/CX with an array

Tags: c++-cx

This following works fine:

```
public value struct Foo {
    Platform::String^ Name; 
    Platform::String^ Type;
};
```

However, when I tried to add an `Platform::Array<double>^` as the following, I will get an error message.

```
public value struct Foo {
    Platform::String^ Name; 
    Platform::String^ Type;
    const Platform::Array<double>^ Value; 
};
```

Error message:

```
signature of public member contains invalid type 'const Platform::Array<double,1> ^
```

I also tried this `const Platform::Array<Platform::String^>^ Values`. But I will have similar error message:

```
signature of public member contains invalid type 'const Platform::Array<Platform::String ^,1> ^'
```

What does this mean? And how do I fix this?

---

Edit: Have to use `class` in this case since `value struct` can contain as fields only fundamental numeric types, enum classes, or `Platform::String^`.

```
public ref class Foo sealed {
    property Platform::String^ Name;
    property Platform::String^ Type;
    property Platform::Array<Platform::String^>^ Values;    
};
```

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14588173/1896761)?

Comment: Apparently a value-type struct can't use generic arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A WinRT `value struct` (or `value class`) can only contain primitive types (numbers, strings, etc.) [[source]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh699861.aspx). It cannot contain arrays or reference types (other than `IReference<T>`).

Thanks to [@Yuchen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1035008/yuchen) for an edit.